# "URL GOTO" keeps looping from iMacros javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, firefox, command-line, imacros

I have two files in the folder ~/iMacros/Macros/ that are related.  One is an imacro (TodaysEvents.iim) like below:

```
VERSION BUILD=8920312 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://www.event.com/schedual
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES

TAG POS={{loop}} TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:02 EXTRACT=HTM

SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=/root/Desktop FILE=TodaysEvents.csv
TAB CLOSE
```

And the other is a javascript file (TodaysEvents.js) like below:

```
var i;
for (i = 1; i < 130; i++) {
 iimSet("loop", i);
 iimPlay("TodaysEvents");
}
```

The way I use them together is:

```
firefox "imacros://run/?m=TodaysEvents.js"
```

When I used these files, I desired to have all the loops completed in the imacros script by only loading the website once.  However, in order to do that from the command line I have to run it from a JavaScript file, hence the two files.  The problem is, although the looping works, the website is reloaded for each loop.  Which file do I edit, and how, so the site is loaded only once, and all the extraction loops are carried out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use only one file "TodaysEvents.js". And let it be like this:

```
const L = "\n";
iimPlayCode("TAB T=1" + L + "URL GOTO=http://www.event.com/schedual" + L);

for (i = 1; i < 130; i++) {
    iimSet("loop", i);
    iimPlayCode("SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + L + "TAG POS={{loop}} TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:02 EXTRACT=HTM" + L + "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=/root/Desktop FILE=TodaysEvents.csv" + L);
}
```

Comment: That's what I have been needing.  Thank you!